# Group mongo collection based on a value if present else dont group, show it as it is

Tags: mongodb, grouping

I want to group the following collection by "Company" attribute, only if Company attribute is available else don't group show as it is

Here is my collection.

```
{
    "_id":"Wagon R",
    "type": "Car",
    "Company": "Suzuki"
},
{
    "_id":"Ertiga",
    "type": "Car",
    "Company": "Suzuki"
},
{
    "_id":"Accent",
    "type": "Car",
    "Company": "Hyundai"
},
{
    "_id":"Camry",
    "type": "Car",
    "Company": "Toyoto"
},
{
    "_id":"Corollo",
    "type": "Car",
    "Company": "Toyoto"
},
{
    "_id":"M 800",
    "type": "Car",
    "Company": ""
},
{
    "_id":"E 800",
    "type": "Car",
},
{
    "_id":"X 800",
    "type": "Car",
}
```

The sample output required.

```
{
    "_id":"Wagon R",
},
{
    "_id":"Accent",
},
{
    "_id":"Camry",
},
{
    "_id":"M 800",
},
{
    "_id":"E 800",
},
{
    "_id":"X 800",
}
```

I tried with grouping, but its giving the collection which only has company attribute. I also want the records which doesnt have company attribute
Can someone please help

```
    {
        "$match" : ----
    },

    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$Company",
        "doc": {"$first":"$$ROOT"}


      }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {"newRoot":"$doc"}
    }
```

Comment: First of all Each car have one company. Please save car data with company name

Comment: Company can by present or empty or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked with help of this query:

```
db.getCollection('test999').aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            groupCompany: 
            { 
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case : { $lt : ["$Company", null]}, then : "$_id"},
                        { case : { $ne : ["$Company", ""]}, then: "$Company"},
                        { case : { $eq : ["$Company",""]}, then : "$_id"} 
                    ]
                    ,default: "default"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$groupCompany",
            "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" }
    }
]);
```